# Using feh --keep-zoom-vp and --zoom fit at the same time?

Tags: images, feh, zoom

If I run:

`feh --keep-zoom-vp *`

Then `feh` will keep the zoom and viewport positioning when browsing through images, as explained in the [manual](https://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/#--keep-zoom-vp). This works as expected

If I run:

`feh --zoom "fill" *`

Then it will open my images to fit the window. This too works as expected. [Manual](https://man.finalrewind.org/1/feh/#--zoom)

However, if I combine them:

`feh --keep-zoom-vp --zoom "fill" *`

Then it does NOT fit the images to the window size, and it starts out at 100%. The 'zoom fill' parameters are ignored. Any way to make them both work?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you say "work". One setting seems to specify how much to dynamically zoom, the other seems to wholly disable dynamically zooming. It's now clear how you want to both not zoom and dynamically zoom to fit at the same time.  Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: I built 3.10-2-g1197daf and manpage doesn't mention `fit`, there is only `--zoom percent | max | fill`. What version are you using?

Comment: @PhilipCouling the one setting is about whether or not feh remembers the zoom of the previous image when you page through photos (as I understand it), and the other setting is about what the initial zoom should be. As I see it, they are two different setting that should be combine-able, no?

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I use version 3.10

Comment: But even the manpage you linked to doesn't mention `--zoom fit`.

Comment: Ahh sorry @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I am honestly not sure if I read it wrong, or if they _just_ changed the syntax with this latest version, but it is apparently called 'zoom "fill"'. I have updated the question.